# How to force un-signed java applications to run

Tags: java, security, permissions

I am trying to access a java-operated ssh/shell terminal on my cPanel, but i keep getting a

```
Application Blocked by Security Settings

Your security settings have blocked a self-signing application from running.
```

I have lowered java's security level to medium in the java control panel, and also added the cPanel's ssh link to the java exception site list, but it still gives me the same blocked message saying that the java applet is requesting a package found on another domain address not specified in the exemption site list.

A really stupid error all I'm trying to do is access my domains shell client.

Google Chrome   37.0.2062.120 (Official Build 281580) m

OS  Windows 8.1

Blink   537.36 (@181352)

JavaScript  V8 3.27.34.17

Java Version 7 update 67

Flash   15.0.0.152

Please help?

Comment: Assuming since it is an applet you're accessing the cPanel from your browser: what browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm, browser, the browser's version, and the version of the Java plugin would help a lot here.  And the OS and version too.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using java7/8 on your system.

In java 7 security settings has increased and applets are now forced to sign their jars.
and add the

```
Permissions: sandbox
```

To the manifest file in the jar.

Adding the site to the exception site list should suffice, if it does not the only thing I can tell you to do is uninstall your current java installment and install version 6 although this is not recommended, the fix should come from the app side.

Comment: which jar file am I writing this to?

Comment: All jars need to be signed.
the manifest file in the main jar/ear/war in the path: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
should have the line:Permissions: sandbox